# Row data change name url for different pages php mysql

Tags: php, html, sql

I am selecting some rows in the database table and want to redirect to another page. It is doing that, but all the time to the same page. What I want to do is give a different target page for which row. When I select a row, I want to change the name and redirect to another page.

Example:

In another page:

- *questionario.php?menuId=1* I want to change for: conceptualization.php?menuId=1
- *questionario.php?menuId=2* I want to change for: security.php?menuId=1

The code is:

```
while ($mostrar = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    $id = $mostrar['menuId'];
    $utilizador = $mostrar['menuNome'];
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['menuID'] = $mostrar['menuId'];
    //echo 'userid:'.$_SESSION['menuID'];
    //echo 'sessionid:'.session_id();
    $_SESSION['menuNome'] = $mostrar['menuNome'];
    // here:
    <a href='questionario.php?menuId=".$id."'> Seleccionar </a> </td>
</tr>");
}
```

Any suggestions for do that?

Comment: Do you have the names "conceptualization" and "security" in your database table? Is it in "menuNome"? Note that in the code an "echo" is missing before `<a href...`. I reformatted your code for better readability and added the most important tag: PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the name of the page using the variable that contains that name. I assume it is retrieved from the database as *$mostrar['menuNome']*:

Change this piece of code:

```
echo ("   ...
<a href='questionario.php?menuId=".$id."'>Seleccionar</a></td></tr>");
```

to:

```
echo ("   ...
<a href='".$mostrar['menuNome'].".php?menuId=".$id."'>Seleccionar</a></td></tr>");
```

And if you really want the menuId to always be passed with value 1, then:

```
echo ("   ...
<a href='".$mostrar['menuNome'].".php?menuId=1'></a>Seleccionar</td></tr>");
```

... but maybe that was a typo in your question.

Now if the name of the page is in another variable, then you need to adapt the above code accordingly.

If you do not have the name of the page anywhere, then I would suggest to add a new column to your database table, and store it. Then you retrieve it with the query you already have, and inject it like above.

Comment: I don´t remember on that way,  Is that i want. Many thanks.